# Is there any example where this particular construction in this proof of Bolzano's theorem doesn't stop after finite steps?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In the following proof of Bolzano's theorem:  http://functionspace.com/topic/1508/opinion/5393 there's this construction of two  sequences $(a_k), (b_k)$ which converge to a point $c$, where $f(c)=0$.

Now, the author basically says, keep subdividing the starting interval, and if after finite steps, in the mid point $c_k$ we have that $f(c_k)=0$, we're done.

If not (as in, the procedure doesn't terminate after whatever number of steps), we have these sequences such that $f(a_k)<0, f(b_k)>0$, etc.

My question is: Using this construction, can you find a function $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ such that the procedure doesn't terminate after a finite number of steps?

Comment: $-\cos\colon [0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$, with $a_0 = 0,\, b_0 = 2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, so I can pick whatever rational interval $[a,b]$ and a function with $f$ with $f(x)=x$ only for irrational $x$ in $[a,b]$, right?

Comment: Even "worse", you can take $f(x) = 3x-1$ with $a_0 = 0,\, b_0 = 1$. The procedure only stops if there is a zero of the form $m 2^{-k} a_0 + \bigl(1 - m 2^{-k}\bigr)b_0$ for some integer $m$ (and the signs are suitable so that you actually reach that zero).

Comment: @DanielFischer If you post any of those (with a short proof) I'll accept it :$)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one is always bisecting the interval $[a_k,b_k]$, there are sequences $(m_k)$ and $(n_k)$ of integers with $0 \leqslant m_k < n_k \leqslant 2^k$ such that

$$a_k = a_0 + \frac{m_k}{2^k}(b_0 - a_0)\quad\text{and}\quad b_k = a_0 + \frac{n_k}{2^k}(b_0 -a_0).\tag{$\ast$}$$

We prove $(\ast)$ by induction. The base case $k = 0$ is clear with $m_0 = 0$ and $n_0 = 1$. For the induction step, we look at $c_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_k + b_k)$, and by the induction hypothesis we have

$$c_{k+1} = a_0 + \frac{m_k + n_k}{2^{k+1}}(b_0 - a_0).$$

Unless $f(c_{k+1}) = 0$ and we stop, we have either $a_{k+1} = c_{k+1}$ and $b_{k+1} = b_k$, in which case $0 <m_{k+1} = m_k + n_k < 2\cdot n_k = n_{k+1} \leqslant 2^{k+1}$, or we have $a_{k+1} = a_k$ and $b_{k+1} = c_{k+1}$, in which case $0 \leqslant m_{k+1} = 2\cdot m_k < m_k + n_k = n_{k+1} < 2^{k+1}$.

So the algorithm can only terminate after finitely many steps if $f$ has a zero at a point

$$z = a_0 + \frac{m}{2^k}\cdot (b_0 - a_0),$$

that is, a point such that the real number $\frac{z-a_0}{b_0 - a_0}$ has a finite binary expansion.

If we take $f(x) = -\cos x$ with $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 2$, the only zero of $f$ in $[0,2]$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, which is irrational, and so the algorithm doesn't terminate after finitely many steps. Also $f(x) = x^2 - 2$ with $a_0 = 1$ and $b_0 = 2$, the only zero $\sqrt{2}$ of $f$ in $[a_0,b_0]$ is irrational, so the algorithm doesn't terminate after finitely many steps.

For $f(x) = 3x-1$ with $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 1$, the algorithm also doesn't terminate, since the binary expansion of $\frac{1}{3}$ is non-terminating.

But it clearly terminates after finitely many steps if we choose e.g. $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = \frac{4}{3}$, like the cosine example terminates if we choose $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 2\pi$.

For every continuous $f$ that has a zero, one can choose $a_0$ and $b_0$ so that the algorithm terminates (after the first step even), but generically, the algorithm doesn't terminate.